# Why are Barry and Oliver wearing their old Flash/Arrow suits in the Legends of Tomorrow trailer?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

At the end of *The Flash - 2x01 - The Man Who Saved Central City*, Cisco shows Barry the newly modified suit - based on the design they saw in Gideon's newspaper projection - prominently featuring the classic white background:

[image: New (White Background) Flash Suit]

In the Trailer for *Legends of Tomorrow* however, he wears the old one again:

[image]

Same goes for Oliver, who recieves his (also Cisco-designed) new suit near the end of *Arrow - 4x01 - Green Arrow*:

[image: New (Green) Arrow Suit]

**Has there been any word from anyone involved in the production as to the reason?**

**PS:** It could of course be a "simple" continuity error based on the fact they shot the footage for the *Legends* trailer before shooting on Season 2 of *The Flash* / Season 4 of *Arrow* even began - although it would be a rather glaring one. *Legends of Tomorrow* also has a time travel component, so that could obviously be a factor as well, or maybe there will be reshoots.

Comment: It's such an obvious thing I can hardly be the only one noticing it, so somebody must have asked the producers. Sadly google doesn't seem to agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Given the relatively rapid pace of change with both Flash and Arrow as well as DC trying to get it's other projects off the ground, (Suicide Squad, Batman v. Superman, Supergirl to name a few) it is most likely the trailers for Legends of Tomorrow were shot with the costumes they had on hand at the time.

- However, given there may be some time travel or alternate universe possibilities in the slowly forming **[DC Extended Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Extended_Universe)**, it is possible, the writers of the show may be completely aware of what would appear to be continuity gaffes.
- The production team may account for them later by either reshooting those scenes or explaining them as time travel issues, in-universe. While having no direct connection to the DC Extended Universe, I imagine shuffling all of these projects simultaneously would be quite challenging and a few things are bound to slip through the cracks.

> - The first film released in the DCEU was Man of Steel (2013), a reboot of the Superman film series. The next film to be released will be Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice (2016), followed by Suicide Squad (2016), with both in post-production. Other films in development include, Wonder Woman (2017), The Flash (2018), Aquaman (2018), Shazam (2019), Cyborg (2020), Green Lantern Corps (2020), and a two-part Justice League film, with Part One releasing in 2017, and Part Two in 2019. Warner Bros. has also announced a sequel to Man of Steel and a stand-alone Batman film, with the intent for both to be released before 2020.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the trailer for *Legends of Tomorrow* is largely composed of footage from season 3 of *Arrow* and season 1 of *The Flash*. The trailer was released in early 2015 to announce the show, back when those seasons of *Arrow/The Flash* were airing. Ergo, it's currently (S4 of *Arrow* and S2 of *The Flash* have just started airing at time of writing) out of date.

In the actual show, it looks like we'll see Green Arrow and Flash in their current outfits.  The latest trailer for *Legends of Tomorrow* shows Oliver briefly at 0:46 and 2:09, and he's wearing his S4 costume:

So the initial trailer having old outfits is merely an artifact of when the trailer was produced.  It likely is unconnected to the show's canon.

Comment: I know (which is why I wrote it in my postscript). The trailer *is* mostly old footage, except the rooftop scene shown in the picture, which was shot at the very end of last season. In fact, Stephen Amell tells a story from when they shot it at NerdHQ at San Diego Comic Con in July ( https://youtu.be/8xc8k5vzhys?t=451)